# Show divergence of an integral with exponential functions

Tags: calculus, integration

How to show the divergence of the following integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp(-\frac{a^2}{2t})dt=\infty.
$$

I was wondering what are the general ways to show the divergence of integrals.

Comment: In general one calculates the divergence of vector fields, not integral expressions. How does the formula you wrote represent a vector field?

Comment: I think that he is referring to the non-convergence of the integral, not the divergence operator $\nabla \cdot$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$e^{-a^2/2t}=1-\frac{a^2}{2t}+O(t^{-2})$$
Using the limit comparison test, and the fact that 
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^{-a^2/2t} t^{-1/2}}{t^{-1/2}}=1$$
We can show that your integral diverges because the following one also diverges:
$$\int_0^{\infty} t^{-1/2}\,dt$$

Edit:

It's also important to show that both functions are integrable around $x=0$. And because $\lim_{x\to0} e^{-a^2/2t} t^{-1/2}=0$ and $\int_0^a t^{-1/2}<\infty$ for any $a\in [0,\infty)$, this is the case.

Comment: You have analyzed it for large $t$. You need to look at it for small $t$, both factors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^\infty t^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{a^2}{2t}}dt=2\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{u^2}e^{-a^2u^2}du=2a\int_0^\infty v^{-2}e^{-v^2}dv=a\int_0^\infty w^{-3/2}e^{-w}dw=a\Gamma(-\frac{1}{2})$$